# If statement inside loop in VBA - excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a Macro with a simple IF statement inside a loop in VBA for Excel. To be honest I have no idea what I am doing. I got the IF statement working, then tried to add a Loop around it - however the loop doesn't work.

Basically I want to write a macro that checks cell F11, then adds the outcome of the IF statement to G11, then drops down to the next row, checks F12, add outcome to G12 etc etc until the end. Below is the code. If anyone could help me with this that would be great!

```
Sub Country()    
    Dim cell As Range    
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("G11:G100")    
        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "AUBNE" Then
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "AUSTRALIA"    
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) = "CNTAO" Then
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "CHINA"    
        Else: ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NA"    
        End If    
    Next cell    
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `ActiveCell` to `cell` and run it again. I think you'll find it working then. (You don't want the cell that is currently selected by the user in the workbook, you want the `cell` that is being defined in the loop). Also instead of `FormulaR1C1` use `Value` since you aren't doing any formula work here.

Comment: I would also not use `Dim cell as Range` since `cell` is too similar to the object `Cells`. Would be easy, and understandable, if someone were to mix the two up. Maybe use `myCell` as your variable? This way the two are easy to distinguish. *This won't fix your code. More of a "best practice" tip*

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so so much! Worked like a charm!

Comment: You can build a table and do this with a vlookup and avoid VBA

Comment: Thanks urdearboy, however the sheet will change each week, and will be used by someone not familiar with excel and tables. So best to write a macro for them to run themselves each week.

Answer (score 0):

If your test statement is to get longer you can also use `Select Case`. It may be a littler cleaner in this case, especially if multiple values are to return the same country.

Also, `myCell` (or anything else) instead of `cell`. It is smart to avoid declaring your own variables that are that close to pre-defined objects. Can lead to confusion/errors later.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Country()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim myCell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each myCell In ws.Range("G11:G100")
        Select Case myCell.Offset(, -1).Value
            Case "AUBNE"
                myCell = "AUSTRALIA"
            Case "CNTAO"
                myCell = "CHINA"
            Case Else
                myCell = "NA"
        End Select
    Next myCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks urdearboy, however this returned a highlighted error at : Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Comment: Updated. You need to change the sheet name in that line (`Sheet1`) to the actual sheet you want this to run on